# Nativescript-angular: How to set a variable from a subscription value that will be accessible in component class scope

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an observable in my BottomNavigationService that returns the "current tab". The "current tab" is a `Subject`: `private _currentTab: Subject<TabName> = new Subject<TabName>();` and the currentTab getter is an observable:

```
public get currentTab() {
  return this._currentTab.asObservable();
}
```

I am attempting to subscribe to this in a Component Page and set a variable local to that component class to use to check the current tab. This code:

```
console.log(`BEFORE SUBSCRIPTION: ${this._currentTabName}`);
this.bottomNavigationService.currentTab.subscribe(tabName => {
  this._currentTabName = tabName;
  console.log(`INSIDE SUBSCRIPTION: ${this._currentTabName}`);
});
console.log(`AFTER SUBSCRIPTION: ${this._currentTabName}`);
```

Is attempting to set a local _currentTabName variable (`private _currentTabName: TabName;`). The logs currently log:

- `INSIDE SUBSCRIPTION: homeTab`
- `BEFORE SUBSCRIPTION: undefined`
- `AFTER SUBSCRIPTION: undefined`

What am I missing here to get this value into my component's local scope so I can use it?

Answer (score 1):

Save the result of your `this.bottomNavigationService.currentTab.subscribe` in a variable that is in your component's scope.

```
export class <YOUR CLASS NAME> {
   navigationSubscription$: Subscription;
................
    navigationSubscription$ = this.bottomNavigationService.currentTab.subscribe(tabName => {
      this._currentTabName = tabName;
      console.log(`INSIDE SUBSCRIPTION: ${this._currentTabName}`);
    });
}
```

Now you can use `navigationSubscription$` to access the subscription and unsubscribe it as well.